# BaseType.Resolve() yielding null for base types in different assembly

Tags: reflection, mono.cecil

I have a method to get all members of a type using mono.cecil, all the way through the type hierarchy, but I've found that often the following statement returns null:

```
(asmType has type 'TypeDefinition')
TypeDefinition baseType = asmType.BaseType.Resolve();
```

Prior to this statement I've checked that asmType.BaseType is not null (and I know  that the base type exists). I think it tends to return null when the base type and derived type are in different assemblies. Both assemblies are being examined by mono.cecil, so I know it's capable of finding and handling both, at least individually.

Is there some way to nudge cecil to correctly resolve the base type?

UPDATE:
If I add this code, it works, but it is not practical as a general solution:

```
if (baseType == null)
{
    var test = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly("<hard-coded explicit path>");
    baseType = test.MainModule.GetType(asmType.BaseType.FullName);
}
```

UPDATE 2:

I tried using:

```
AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(asmType.BaseType.Module.FileName)
```

But 'FileName' for some reason is the file name of 'asmType' (derived type) and not the base type ?

UPDATE 3:

I was able to work-around the problem by using my own cache for AssemblyDefinition which only records non-null values. The mono.cecil code adds possibly null values into its cache in the DefaultAssemblyResolver class, even though its possible to resolve the assembly successfully at a later point after that first attempt. The cecil 'Resolve' method in the DefaultAssemblyResolver class will never resolve an assembly after an initial attempt produces null since it will always later return the cached null value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a better work-around - but this just looks in already-read assemblies and looks for the base class there. Very strange that mono.cecil doesn't do this consistently:

```
private static readonly Dictionary<string, AssemblyDefinition> _AssemblyDefinitions = new();

//whenever 'AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly' is called, add to _AssemblyDefinitions if non-null, with the key being the AssemblyDefinition FullName

private static TypeDefinition TypeReferenceToTypeDefinition(TypeReference typeReference)
{
    TypeDefinition typeDefinition = typeReference.Resolve();

    //mono.cecil may possibly return a null value from its cache in the DefaultAssemblyResolver.Resolve method:
    if (typeDefinition == null)
    {
        if (_AssemblyDefinitions.TryGetValue(typeReference.Scope.ToString(), out AssemblyDefinition foundAssemblyDefinition))
            typeDefinition = foundAssemblyDefinition.MainModule.GetType(typeReference.FullName);
    }

    return typeDefinition;
}
```

Debugging mono.cecil shows that in the 'DefaultAssemblyResolver' class, the 'cache' dictionary sometimes has an item added with the AssemblyDefinition being null, so for my specific case, 'Resolve' returned the null item from the cache. My own version of 'cache' had a non-null item (I don't add null values to my cache, so if ReadAssembly returns null once it's not doomed forever to be null). I haven't figured out why mono.cecil adds null items to its cache.

Answer (score 1):

I don't known which version of Cecil you are using, but looking in `0.1.14` code I see it is possible to reproduce this behavior at least in 3 different ways:

1. Having a custom assembly resolver that fails to resolve the assembly containing the type.
2. If the `Scope` of that type is `null`.
3. If the `Scope` of that type references the wrong assembly.

Notice that if I don´t specify an **assembly resolver** (or set it to **null**) then Cecil throws an `AssemblyResolutionException` exception.

If you are changing these assemblies through Cecil(other than simply reading / processing) then my best bet is that you are hitting either **2** or **3**.

BTOH, if you are simply reading the assemblies **and** you have custom *assembly resolver*, then **1** would be my best bet.

Below is an example code that I used to play with it. Basically it loads an assembly (*libb*) and gets a type which has a `BaseType` defined in another assembly (*liba*) **that is not in the same folder as libb**, i.e, Cecil will not be able to resolve that assembly.

```
using System;
using Mono.Cecil;

IAssemblyResolver ar = null;
if (args.Length > 0 && args[0] == "resolver")
{
    Console.WriteLine("Using bad assembly resolver...");
    ar = new MyAssemblyResolver();
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Using default assembly resolver...");
}

var a = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly("../libb/bin/Debug/net6.0/libb.dll", new ReaderParameters() { AssemblyResolver = ar } );
var t = a.MainModule.GetType("libb.InLibB");

if (args.Length > 0 && args[0] == "null")
{
    Console.WriteLine("Setting scope to null.");
    t.BaseType.Scope = null;
}

if (args.Length > 0 && args[0] == "ms")
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Setting scope to {a.MainModule.TypeSystem.Object.Scope}.");
    t.BaseType.Scope = a.MainModule.TypeSystem.Object.Scope;
}

Console.WriteLine($"Type = {t.FullName}");
Console.WriteLine($"BaseType = {t.BaseType.FullName}");
Console.WriteLine($"BaseType.Resolve() != null: {t.BaseType.Resolve() != null}");


class MyAssemblyResolver : Mono.Cecil.BaseAssemblyResolver
{
    public override AssemblyDefinition Resolve (AssemblyNameReference name, ReaderParameters parameters) => null;
}
```

Comment: I'm using DefaultAssemblyResolver and the 2 dlls are in the same folder. The 'Scope' of both dlls are non-null and correct. The scopes reference the correct assemblies.

Comment: See the 'update' section - if I hard-code the assembly path to get the base type it works, but obviously this is a crap solution.

Comment: interesting. If it is 100% reproducible you can build Cecil locally and debug.

Comment: Why would the 'Scope' of a type reference the wrong assembly? This is related to the problem I think.

Comment: the only scenarios I can think of are: 1) a bug in Cecil, 2) your code may be setting it explicitly; 3) a assembly resolver returning the wrong assembly

but you said you are using DefaultAssemblyResolver and the Scope of the TypeReferences were correct; 

Are you doing any kind of assembly modification in that code?

Comment: The 'Module' for the base type is incorrect (specifies the derived type Module), but the 'Scope' is correct. This is why my hacky work-around gets the directory of the Module, and then appends the Scope name.

Comment: it looks like your understanding of "Module" is incorrect; this property specifies the module in which the reference was made, not the module in which the referenced type is declared ( this program shows this: https://cutt.ly/gV8L98H)

Comment: So my "ResolvedBaseType" is the appropriate or expected way to resolve a base type from a TypeReference ?  Seems like a hack...

Comment: doesn't look like to me. I am not aware of anything special you need to do this. It looks like some other issue.

Comment: Thanks for your help. After understanding that 'Module' for a TypeReference is not key to the problem, I was able to come up with a better work-around (see my new answer to my  own question). Mono.cecil usually resolves the base type fine, but occasionally misses it - still haven't determined the exact cause for the occasional miss though.